# How do I get the names of the roles from a map that gives only true or false?

Tags: javascript, discord

This code snippet only prints true or false, how do I get the names of the roles?

```js
console.log(message.guild.roles.cache.map(r => r.name.startsWith('pro')).join(', '))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`String.prototype.startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) returns `true` or `false` whether the string starts with the specified value or not. The [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) iterates through each element of the array and returns the output of the provided callback. This is why your code is returning `true` or `false`.

You can use the [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function to return each item which passes your criteria. A simple example:

```js
const a = ["abc","aadc","bdc","asdk","kkk"]
        
console.log(a.filter((value) => value.startsWith("a"))) 
// returns ["abc","aadc","asdk"]
```

Your solution:

```js
console.log(message.guild.roles.cache.filter(r => r.name.startsWith('pro')).join(','))
```

Comment: ok it works, it returns all the information of the role but I can't get the name

Comment: I tried this and it worked ```console.log(message.guild.roles.cache.filter(r => r.name.startsWith('pro')).map(r => r.name).join(', '));```